# puppet 4.0 vagrant modules missing

Tags: centos, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to use puppet modules in vagrant.
My box is running puppet 4.0

I am installing modules using:

```
if [ ! -d /etc/puppet/modules/ ]; then 
    puppet module install puppetlabs-java
fi
```

in `site.pp` 
I have:

```
class { 'java': 
    distribution => 'jdk',
}
```

I keep getting an error about `could not find declared class java`
why can't puppet find my module?

`/etc/puppet/modules/` is the default path isn't it?

vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.2"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
    vb.memory = "8192"
  end
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "upgrade_puppet.sh"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "puppet_modules.sh"

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.options = '--verbose --debug'
    puppet.environment_path = "puppet/environments"
    puppet.environment = "production"  
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer now that Vagrantfile has been provided**

Locations have changed in puppet 4 and [directory environments](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/whered_it_go.html#directory-environments-are-always-on) are now in use by default.

So how you are using the puppet provisioner is correct. However, vagrant will upload all the directories it needs to the guest, based on your Vagrantfile to:
/tmp/vagrant-puppet/environments/production

When Vagrant calls the puppet apply it will be looking for the modules it requires in:
/tmp/vagrant-puppet/environments/production/modules

and that module directory does not exist on your host.

You can change your if block to be:

```
if [ ! -d /vagrant/puppet/environments/production/modules ]; then
    puppet module install puppetlabs-java --modulepath /vagrant/puppet/environments/production/modules
fi
```

/vagrant is shared between host and guest. This would install the java module and its dependencies on your host machine under:

```
puppet
|
+--environments
   +
   -- production
      |
      + -- manifests
      |    +
      |    -- site.pp
      |
      + -- modules
           +
           -- java
           +
           -- stdlib
```

When you do your vagrant up, this content gets uploaded to the host under:

```
/tmp/vagrant-puppet
```

Tested and confirmed based on your Vagrantfile.

Comment: I still get `Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement. Could not find declared class java at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:1:1`

Comment: @KillerSnail Could you post your Vagrantfile? Also, What version of vagrant are you using?

Comment: vagrant 1.7.4 vagrant file posted above

Comment: @KillerSnail Thanks for posting your Vagrantfile. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Jaxim mentions, it's because the default directory locations have changed in the newer version of Puppet.

If you're interested in installing moduels automatically with Puppet, I'd recommend the R10K vagrant plugin, you can specify versions of modules and make updating them much easier, and allows you to download modules not on the forge, such as git repos.

https://github.com/jantman/vagrant-r10k

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I am switching from Chef over to Puppet (company policy, do not ask! :) ) and ran into the exact same situation and coming from Chef background I was refusing to "pollute" my project folder with so many Puppet specific stuff. In my opinion, I should only need Vagrantfile and nothing else.

I was also getting the "Could not find declared class java at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/environments/production" error message. So, after much messing around I've found that in `puppet.options` you can provide any arguments that you would normally provide if calling `puppet apply` at the command line.

So, if anything helps try modifying the puppet.options in your Vagrantfile as follows:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.options = '--verbose --modulepath=/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules'
  puppet.environment_path = "puppet/environments"
  puppet.environment = "production"  
end
```

This will help Puppet find its own nose and not think that everything is available at the /tmp folder, but that the modules have already been installed at its own folder location.